# Convert datatable date into dd/mm/yyyy format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datatable

I have a `datatable` in which I want to get the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Currently I get date like

> 02-01-2012 12:00:00 AM

Below is my code

```
strInvoice_date = dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"].ToString();
```

Comment: What is the column type of your `INVOICE_DATE` in your `dt`? Is it `DateTime` or `string`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Convert* and then *represent* as you want:

```
  strInvoice_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: I think generally it would be better to use `ParseExact` in this kind of cases because _this_ format _might_ not be a standard date and time format for OP's `CurrentCulture` since `Convert.ToDateTime(object)` _probably_ calls `ToString` method inside of it. But since OP selected this as an answer, it is not valid for this case :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"]` retuns `object` and when you call `ToString` method, it will call [`object.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring) **not** [`DateTime.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring).

If your `INVOICE_DATE` column is `DateTime` in your datatable, you can explicitly cast your `object` to `DateTime` and use `dd/MM/yyyy` (I assume you want months instead of minutes) format with a *proper* culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
var Invoice_date = (DateTime)dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"]
                               .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your `INVOICE_DATE` column is `string` in your datatable, you need to get it's string representation with `object.ToString`, parse it to `Datetime`, and generate it's string representation.

```
var Invoice_date = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"].ToString(), 
                                      "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                          .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This is the better way to go, to save headaches it's important to define the culture info.

Answer (score 0):

You've to pass the required date format in ToString() method,

```
 strInvoice_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"]).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

For more details on date time formatting, [visit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: getting error as `no overload for method takes 1 arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Below Code can Help You

```
strInvoice_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"].ToString("0:dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: `dt.Rows[i]["INVOICE_DATE"]` returns `object` and there is no overload for `object.ToString()` that takes `string` as a parameter.

Comment: You need convert the column with DateTime.  strInvoice_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]"INVOICE_DATE"].ToString("0:dd/MM/yyyy"));