# C# change date format from dd/MM/yy to dd/MM/yyyy in datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I tried to convert dd/MM/yy to dd/MM/yyyy using this code:

```
int i = 0;
string d = "";

foreach(DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["FinData"].Rows)

{
    d = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["Date"], "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["date"] = d;
    i++; 
}
```

but it seems I have a problem with datetime.parseexact usage.

How can modify it?

Here is the full coding:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo formatProvider = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
formatProvider.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = DateTime.Now.Year;

label1.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;

Uri url = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=KRX%3A005930&ei=-gUcWcG4Aom_0AS2sKyoBg&start=30&num=30&output=csv");

wc.DownloadFile(url, label1.Text + @"\finance.csv");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(label1.Text + @"\finance.csv", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
dataset.Tables.Add("FinData");
dataset.Tables["FinData"].Columns.Add("Date");
dataset.Tables["FinData"].Columns.Add("Open");
dataset.Tables["FinData"].Columns.Add("High");
dataset.Tables["FinData"].Columns.Add("Low");
dataset.Tables["FinData"].Columns.Add("Close");
dataset.Tables["FinData"].Columns.Add("Volume");

string item;

while ((item = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

{
    myArr = item.Split(',');
    dataset.Tables["FinData"].Rows.Add(myArr);
}

int i = 0;
string d = "";

foreach(DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["FinData"].Rows)

{
    d = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["Date"], "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["date"] = d;
    i++; 
}
```

Comment: If the column in the DataTable is set to DataTime then the table doesn't need to be changed.  I'm not sure why you are trying to parse a Date that is already a DataTime object.  If you want to display a DataTime in another format then use ToString(enter correct format)

Comment: He is confused about how datetime works clearly.  What you are attempting to do @Hong is only valid if it was something like a varchar column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert datatable date into dd/mm/yyyy format in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644338/convert-datatable-date-into-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-asp-net)

Comment: reduced indentation to make post easier to read and improved structure of text

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToFourDigitYear method to convert YY to YYYY

```
        string strDate = "31/12/17";
        System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar gregCal = new System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar();
        DateTime dtDate = new DateTime(gregCal.ToFourDigitYear(Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Substring(6, 2))), Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Substring(0, 2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

It seems to me that there is already an answer here:[Convert datatable date into dd/mm/yyyy format in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644338/convert-datatable-date-into-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file (of which you kindly provided the semi-encrypted link) contains dates like "28-Mar-17". Even if `DateTime.ParseExact` is new to you, it shouldn't be hard to infer from its name that it parses a date string *exactly* according to the given format, which isn't "dd/MM/yy". So this is how to use it:

```
d = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["Date"], "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: why it keep saying with   dr["Date"]

'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: I don't understand. The way you define your datatable, the data type of the Date column should be string. Otherwise, use `dr["Date"].ToString()`.